# How to append and save data to array of dictionaries [String:[String]]

Tags: swift

I have populated an array with elements conforming to a struct in the following format:

```
Struct Domain {
    var name: String
    var areas: [String]
}

let myArray = [
    Domain(name: "name1", areas: ["area1A", "area1B"]),
    Domain(name: "name2", areas: ["area2A", "area2B", "area2C"]),
    Domain(name: "name3", areas: ["area3A"])
]
```

I know how to append new Domain objects to myArray, but how can I append new areas entries for existing Domain objects in myArray?

Answer (score 0):

Change your array let to var

```
var myArray = [
        Domain(name: "name1", areas: ["area1A", "area1B"]),
        Domain(name: "name2", areas: ["area2A", "area2B", "area2C"]),
        Domain(name: "name3", areas: ["area3A"])
    ]
```

find index of domain that you want to change

```
if let indexOfdomain = myArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == "name2"}) {
            myArray[indexOfdomain] = Domain(name: "name2", areas: ["area3A"])
        }

        print(myArray)
```